# Missing / Receiving incorrect settlement report through MWS API

Tags: amazon-mws

Some times we are getting incorrect settlement report and some times we missing some settlement report using ‘_GET_V2_SETTLEMENT_REPORT_DATA_FLAT_FILE_V2_’ report of MWS Report API.
I am requesting settlement report for previous fifteen days to current date as below.

```
 request.AvailableFromDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-15);
 request.AvailableToDate = DateTime.Now;
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Is there anything I need to check for correct settlement report?

Do our Seller need to have some settings on Seller central account for this?